# How to have Pig feed multiple files into one mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

Is it possible to have Pig process several small files with one mapper (assuming doing so will improve the speed of the job). We have an issue where there are thousands of small files in hdfs and pig creates hundreds of mappers. Is there a simple (full or partial) solution that Pig provides to address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of these properties to combine these multiple files into one file, so that they are processed by a single map :

- **pig.maxCombinedSplitSize** – Specifies the size, in bytes, of data to be processed by a single map. Smaller files are combined untill this size is reached.
- **pig.splitCombination** – Turns combine split files on or off (set to “true” by default).

This feature works with PigStorage without having to write any custom loader. More on this can be found [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/perf.html#combine-files).

HTH

Comment: I have been trying to use this feature with PigStorage. With TextLoader I can run jobs. However, with PigStorage it hangs before submitting the job to the cluster (last log line is: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at ...). I don't know what it is doing. Since I am running the Pig client from outside the cluster, I hope it is not sending the HDFS files over the network to combine them? I would love to know how this combination feature works but I haven't found any usable information.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach in Hadoop with a large number of small files is to aggregate them into large Sequence or Avro files and than use respective storage functions to read them.
For Pig and Avro take a look at [AvroStorage](https://cwiki.apache.org/PIG/avrostorage.html)

Comment: We will get there soon :)